# I think the persisted model documentation is gone

Tags: loopbackjs

I was looking for some information about the function User.destroyAll() which brought me to [that page](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-updating-and-deleting-data.html#deleting-data).

Clicking on the link for information about destroyAll sends me to http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#persistedmodel-destroyall
which seems like the right address, except it's actually the beginning of the documentation and the exact same thing as travelling to that page http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/ .

This made me realise that there are no documentation pieces about persisted-model anymore.

Is it a bug? Do you know when this will come back?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you are right. There is documentation for PersistedModel for version one before last http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/v/3.19.3/ but it disappeared in version 3.20.0 http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/v/3.20.0/ So if you need documentation you can use this for version 3.19.3. According to the changelog, there were no changes related to PersistedModel

```
Update strong-globalize to 4.x (Miroslav Bajtoš)

Update nodemailer to v4.x (Dimitris)

Drop support for Node.js 4.x (Miroslav Bajtoš)
```